Binary conversation from decimal to binary
While doing the binary learning , i have came acrossed the below one . if you some help on that it would be grateful..
Why does decimal value become '-1', when the binary value  will be 16 consecutive of 1's  bit  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
enter image description here

Bits don't have a "decimal value" until you interpret them. If you interpret them as a signed integer (in the most common format) then all-1 will be -1, due to that using the two's complement to represent negative values. If you interpret it as an unsigned number it will be the highest integer value representable with that amount of bits.

It isn't necessarily -1 until something chooses to interpret the value as signed number.  Here's that's your calculator choosing to look at it as signed and show the value in decimal.  For further reading see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations.  Most computer systems choose 2's complement for signed integer representation, b/c that eliminates the need for separate arithmetic hardware for both signed and unsigned (e.g. addition, subtraction) and/or for historical and compatibility reasons.

In binary representation, the value you described, "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111", is actually the binary representation of -1 in two's complement notation when interpreted as a signed integer.
In two's complement notation, the most significant bit (leftmost bit) represents the sign of the number. If it's 0, the number is positive, and if it's 1, the number is negative.
Let's break down why "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111" represents -1:
The leftmost bit is 1, indicating that the number is negative.
The remaining bits "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111" represent the binary value for positive 1.
When interpreted as a negative number in two's complement notation, the value is calculated by taking the two's complement of the positive value and adding 1.
The two's complement of positive 1 is "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001".
Adding 1 to the two's complement gives "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010", which overflows, leaving only the lower 64 bits, resulting in "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111".
Therefore, "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111" represents -1 in two's complement notation.

Thanks for the explanation  , may my next question would be silly  :)
How the overflow will be happen if we adding 1 to the two's complement
Adding 1 to the two's complement gives "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010", which overflows,

I don't think the last sentences make any sense (AI generated?). 000...0001 + 1 does not overflow.

"The leftmost bit is 1, indicating that the number is negative." — true.  Though "The remaining bits "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111" represent the binary value for positive 1." — not actually true. Still, "the two's complement of positive 1 is "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001"" — true.  While "Adding 1 to the two's complement gives "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010"" — true, yet "which overflows" — is false, and also doesn't lead to the desired conclusion.

FYI, if you delete this answer you'll get your rep back..
